# What's the difference between dynamic and static strain aging?

Tags: condensed-matter, crystallography, physical-properties-of-materials, solid-state-physics

I do understand how static strain aging occurs and why the yield point comes back if ample time is allotted after a loading and unloading cycles primarily due to diffusion of substitutional and interstitial impurities in the form of Nitrogen and Carbon.However I do not understand how dynamic strain aging(Portvein -LeChatelier effect) works.Particularly the phenomenon and also the mechanism and properties behind it.A detailed explanation behind this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned (OP has not appeared on the site for over half a year). If someone can provide an answer, I can reopen the question.